# urllib.urlretrieve downloads empty zip files

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to download a export of space in a zip file. But somehow python downloads a empty and corrupted zip file. When you download the file manual by the browser everything is ok.

I use Python 2.7.13

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xmlrpclib
import time
import urllib

confluencesite = "https://confluence.com"
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(confluencesite + '/rpc/xmlrpc')
username = '*'
password = '*'
token = server.confluence2.login(username, password)
loginString = "?os_username=" + username + "&amp;os_password=" + password
filelist = ""
start = True
spacesummary = server.confluence2.getSpaces(token)
for space in spacesummary:
    #if space['name'] == "24-codING":
    #    start = True
    #    continue
    if start:
        if space['type'] == 'global':
            print "Exporting space " + space['name']
            spaceDownloadUrl = server.confluence2.exportSpace(token, space['key'],
                                                              "TYPE_XML",
                                                              exportAll['true'])
            filename = spaceDownloadUrl.split('/')[-1].split('#')[0].split('?')[0]
            time.sleep(0.5)
            urllib.urlretrieve(spaceDownloadUrl + loginString, filename)
            print filename + " saved."
            f = open("exportedspaces.txt", 'a')
            f.write(filename + "\n")
            f.close()
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb the zipfile is produced by the exportSpace API action, that creates the zipfile that can be downloaden. For example: Confluence-space-export-122851-90.xml.zip

Comment: Should probably change `&amp;` to `&`.

Answer (score 2):

It's solved by the answer of Coldspeed. Changing the following:

```
loginString = "?os_username=" + username + "&amp;os_password=" + password
to
loginString = "?os_username=" + username + "&os_password=" + password
```

Comment: Kids, always be sure to sanitise your url parameters. OP, do mark your answer accepted and close this question. Cheers.